# PUT Presigned URL expires before download of file completes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, pre-signed-url

Bit of an odd case where my API is sent a presigned URL to write to, and a presigned URL to download the file from.

The problem is that if they send a very large file, the presigned url we need to write to can expire before it gets to that step (some processing happens in between the read/write).

Is it possible to 'open' the connection for writing early to make sure it doesn't expire, and then start writing once the earlier process is done? Or maybe there is a better way of handling this.

The order goes:

1. Receive API request with a downloadUrl and an uploadUrl
2. Download the file
3. Process the file
4. Upload the file to the uploadUrl

TL;DR: How can I ensure the url for #4 doesn't expire before I get to it?

Comment: you could extend the lifetime of the presigned url, how long is it currently valid?

Comment: The problem is we are being sent the presignedUrl so we don't have control over it (or the bucket it's going into). Our API is basically used for doing some fancy processing for them. We plan on asking them to be generous with the lifetime to be safe, but I was looking for if there was a more guaranteed option.

Comment: The only guarantee here requires the provider to enhance the options available to you. They either extend the time limit or they offer you separate APIs for getting the download and upload URLs.

Answer (score 1):

When generating the pre-signed URL, you have complete control over the time duration. For example, this Java code shows how to set the time when creating a **GetObjectPresignRequest**  object:

```
 GetObjectPresignRequest getObjectPresignRequest =  GetObjectPresignRequest.builder()
                            .signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                            .getObjectRequest(getObjectRequest)
                            .build();
```

So you can increase the time limit in such situations.

Comment: The problem is we are being sent the presignedURL and don't have control of that time. Right now we are just asking them to be generous with the expiration of the write url, but I was looking for a more guaranteed solution if one exists.

Comment: The only solution is setting the value when you create the GetObjectPresignRequest object.